# TeXworks resizes and repositions the PDF viewer window when the document is compiled, and I don't want it to

Tags: texworks

I'm using TeXworks to compile documents and view the LaTeX output. However, I am editing the documents in another application, and TeXworks does not work well with this arrangement. When compilation is requested, if the main .tex file has been altered by another application since the last compilation, TeXworks will resize and reposition the PDF viewer window for no obvious reason. Moreover, the configuration to which it resets the window is frequently one that makes no sense; for the small test document I've been working on today it resets the PDF viewer window to a small, approximately square window in one corner of the screen. [Before](http://junk.orderofthehammer.com/j2013/texworks-bad-resizing-behaviour-before.png) and [after](http://junk.orderofthehammer.com/j2013/texworks-bad-resizing-behaviour-after.png) screenshots of this behaviour, linked because they are large.

I don't want it to change the window's configuration at all once I've set it up the way I like it, but it's especially annoying when it chooses such a daft setup to reset to. I notice that it doesn't reset the scroll position of the window, only its size and position. This happens only if the .tex file has been altered by another program; it does not happen if the file has been changed within the TeXworks editing window. It does not happen if another file that is `\input` by the .tex file has been changed; only if the main file is changed.

There does not appear to be an option in the TeXworks preferences that governs this behaviour. Can it be prevented somehow (aside from creating a "dummy" file that does nothing more than `\include` another file which I actually edit)?

According to the TeXworks "about" dialog box, I am running `version 0.4.5 r.1280 (MikTeX 2.9 64-bit)`. According to [this page](http://www.tug.org/texworks/), this is the latest version. I am running Windows 7 Home Premium Service Pack 1, 64-bit.